# Teamcity build error RUNREADYTORUNCOMPILER with amazon services

Tags: c#, teamcity

I am using aws services in net core 3.1. I have set up standalone step in teamcity to provide me standalone exe file when publishing the project.

I am getting unusuall error while trying to build this on team city. Anyone with similar issues?

Trying to run a command in teamcity:

> dotnet.exe publish --configuration Release --output ..\publish-win-x64
>   @C:\BuildAgent2\temp\agentTmp\21.rsp --no-restore -r win-x64
>   --self-contained:true /p:SolutionDir=.. /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishReadyToRun=true /p:PublishReadyToRunShowWarnings=true
>   /p:PublishTrimmed=false /p:Version=3.16.1.17490-ff-2393-game-me
>   /p:DisableSwagger=%isProduction% /p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=true
>   /warnaserror

Getting an error:

> RUNREADYTORUNCOMPILER : error : Method not found: 'Void
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Transform.JsonUnmarshallerContext..ctor(System.IO.Stream,
>   Boolean, Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Transform.IWebResponseData)'. while
>   resolving 0xa0003df -
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Transform.JsonUnmarshallerContext..ctor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by installing latest version of awssdk dynamodbv2 packages.